# Access denied while saving image in UWP.Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml, win2d

I am working on universal windows app on Windows 10 SDK to draw rectangle on faces recognized in the image.

I am using Win2D to edit the pictures and draw rectangle on it. I am able to read files from the Pictures library but when I try to save the image after editing it gives the following error:

> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   (E_ACCESSDENIED))

The following is the method I used to draw rectangle on the image:

```
private async void DrawRect()
    {
        CanvasDevice device = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice();
        CanvasBitmap bitmap = null;
        CanvasRenderTarget offscreen = null;

        Windows.Storage.StorageFile photofile = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFileAsync("image.jpg");

        if(photofile != null)
        {
            using (var stream = await photofile.OpenReadAsync())
            {
                bitmap = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(device, stream);
            }
        }

        if(bitmap != null)
        {
            offscreen = new CanvasRenderTarget(device, bitmap.SizeInPixels.Width, bitmap.SizeInPixels.Height, 96);
            using (var ds = offscreen.CreateDrawingSession())
            {
                ds.Clear(Colors.Transparent);
                ds.DrawImage(bitmap);
                ds.DrawRectangle(25, 35, 270, 352, Colors.Blue,4);
            }

            var photoFile = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync("image2.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);                        

            if (photofile != null)
            {
                await offscreen.SaveAsync(photofile.Path);
            }              

            //await offscreen.SaveAsync(photoFile.Path);*/
        }
    }
```

The exception is thrown at the last line offscreen.SaveAsync.

The stack trace for the above error is:

> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>      at IdentifyFacesApp.IdentifiedFaces.d__5.MoveNext()

I have set the permissions for accessing the pictures folders in the appmanifest file.

Do I need to set some additional permissions to save the image in the disk.

The same error occurs when I tried to save the image in any other location.

Comment: Have you tried adding all permissions relating to file access and seeing if it works? If it is permissions you can then remove and see which one breaks... Bit of trial and error but wouldnt take a few minutes!

Comment: Yes, I set the permissions in capabilities in appxmanifest. But nothing worked out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to access the file by the stream, not the path:

```
var photoFile = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync("image2.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

if (photofile != null)
{
    using (var stream = await photofile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        await offscreen.SaveAsync(stream, CanvasBitmapFileFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

In UWP if you access files via path, you will likely get *Access Denied* in many cases, it should be done via *StorageFile*.