# How to get a file from a filepath

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a string array fileContentArray, which contains a list of filepath.

```
fileContentArray[0]    D:\Downloads\KuGou\1.mp3
fileContentArray[1]    E:\Downloads\2.mp3
fileContentArray[2]    F:\KuGou\3.mp3
```

And

```
List<StorageFile> files = new List<StorageFile>();
```

I want to add the files into the list

```
private async Task ReadListAsync()
        {
            StorageFolder sFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            StorageFile sf = await sFolder.CreateFileAsync("List.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            using (IRandomAccessStream readStream = await sf.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                using (DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(readStream))
                {
                    UInt64 size = readStream.Size;
                    if (size <= UInt32.MaxValue)
                    {
                        UInt32 numBytesLoaded = await dataReader.LoadAsync((UInt32)size);
                        string fileContent = dataReader.ReadString(numBytesLoaded);
                        string[] fileContentArray = fileContent.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                        List<StorageFile> files = new List<StorageFile>();
                        foreach (string filepath in fileContentArray)
                        {
                            StorageFile sff = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filepath);
                            files.Add(sff);
                        }

                        await AddStorageFilestoList(files);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But when I run the code, it tells me wrong while GetFileFromPathAsync.

> {System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 拒绝访问。
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at MP3Tag.Views.MasterDetailPage.d__31.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at MP3Tag.Views.MasterDetailPage.d__10.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at MP3Tag.Views.MasterDetailPage.d__9.MoveNext()}

In my another app, the almost same code, works.

```
string strLastFile = (Application.Current as App).localSettings.Values["LastFile"] as string;
                if (strLastFile != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(strLastFile);
                        await LoadFileAsync(file);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        //文件不存 
                    }
                }
```

It's just a local app, read a txt file, which contains a list of filepath.
I want to show some info about the files.
How to use it in the correct way?
Thx.

Comment: `it tells me wrong while GetFileFromPathAsync` Can you share with us the details of how it told you wrong?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx may be of assistance.

Comment: mhh maybe the problem is that your paths contains backslashes which has to be escaped.

Comment: Appears to be a permission issue. I also see a `MasterDetailPage` in your error message. Are you trying to access the local filesystem inside a web application? If so, make sure the user of the application pool/webserver is authorized to access local disks. For a production system, you shouldn't do this, for obvious reasons, but it might solve your issue.

Comment: The are multiple questons addressing file access problems in UWP already ([sample](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42599136/2681948)). In UWP don't access files by path, use brokers - *StorageFIle/StorageFolder*.

Comment: This is it: `UnauthorizedAccessException` it means what it says. You do not have permission. If you need to access the whole system you need full system access.

Comment: The path of "F:\KuGou\3.mp3" is a location that you app can't directly access. While dealing with files or folders in UWP, one important rule is [Skip the path: stick to the StorageFile](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/12/04/skip-the-path-stick-to-the-storagefile/).